# SAS (24 hour) time conversion to minutes

Tags: datetime, type-conversion, sas

I am trying to convert 24 hour Time values to minutes

From:

```
(TIME)
17:00:00 
16:55:00
17:30:00
```

To:

```
(NUM)
1060
993
1038
```

Currently I am multiplying the time values by 60 `17*60`, `16.55*60`, `17.30*60`

How would I accomplish this? am I doing it right? and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would **STRONGLY** suggest editing that post for formatting and proper grammar, as your question is unclear, as is your methods of performing the action.

Comment: I'd also check those NUM values, as they're wrong according to my math.  17:00 is 1020 minutes, and 16:55 is not 16.55 but about 16.92, or 1015 minutes; 17:30 is 1050 minutes (and clearly more than 17:00 anyway).

Comment: @Sampath_T . . . Why is this tagged SQL ?

Comment: Are these values durations, or 'minutes since start of day'?  What time zone are they in - do you have to worry about Daylight Savings Time?

Comment: removed SQL and SAS tags: this has nothing to do with SQL or SAS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea what this has to do with SQL, but in general, assuming that *hours* is 0-23 rather than 0-12 with an am/pm indicator, this pseudocode

```
  ( 60.0 * hours )    // convert 0-23 hours to minutes
+ minutes             // minutes don't need conversion
+ ( seconds / 60.0 )  // convert 0-59 seconds to fractional minute
```

should give you the offset from start of day (midnight, 00:00:00) as a fractional number of minutes. If you've got an am/pm indicator, you need to factor that in, something like this:

```
  ( 60.0 * ( hours + ( isPM ? 12 : 0 ) ) ) // convert 0-23 hours to minutes
+ minutes                                  // minutes don't need conversion
+ ( seconds / 60.0 )                       // convert 0-59 seconds to fractional minutes
```

Answer (score 2):

SAS time values are stored as seconds.  If it's truly a 'time' value, anyway, and not a character string. Thus, you can DIVIDE by 60, rather than multiplying.

```
data want;
input timeval TIME9.;
minutes=timeval/60;
format minutes BEST12.;
format timeval TIME9.;
put timeval= minutes=;
datalines;
17:00:00
16:55:00
17:30:00
;;;;
run;
```

If it's not stored as a time value (numeric) but as a string, you need to INPUT(timeval,TIME9.) in order to do that; so

```
minutes = input(timeval,TIME9.)/60;
```

would work.

Comment: This assumes that the time value is some sort of duration.  If it's 'time of day', and reflects a time-zone with DST, this will fail... weirdly.

Comment: That's pretty clearly what the OP stated, given the examples and (slightly inaccurate) results.  I don't think SAS time values (as opposed to DATETIME) ever include time zones or daylight savings, do they?

Comment: I dunno, I've never worked with SAS (although what I do work with, DB2 on the iSeries, doesn't have them).  Given the phrase '24 hour time values' in the post, I'm assuming this _is_ time-of-day... which makes simply dividing this way pointless, if these aren't UTC times (or some other timezone that will never use DST).

Comment: Nah, this is (at least, appears to be) a SAS time value.  SAS time values are explicitly what my comment says - a number of seconds construed as a time; ie, a duration.  DATETIME is the SAS format for any sort of specific time, and more similar to the SQL concept.  As far as I know, you can't have any sense of DST or time-zone with a TIME value, though I certainly could be wrong.  In any event, using a TIME format for anything other than a duration would be at minimum highly confusing.

Comment: Hi Joe,Thanks for your replies ...yeah calculations were wrong ...I found a way to find the minutes because of your reply... Hour(Schd_strt_ts) as SCHD_STR_HR,
Minute(Schd_strt_ts) as SCHD_STR_MN,
((Calculated SCHD_STR_HR)*60)+Calculated SCHD_STR_MN as SCHD_START